# SQL Server: How to check child node exist or not in xml when using xquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery

This how I am iterating in XML data and extracting value from XML.

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <PeriodData>
    <PeriodType>ANNUALONLY</PeriodType>
    <Period>2010 FY</Period>
  </PeriodData>
  <PeriodData>
    <PeriodType>ANNUALONLY</PeriodType>
    <Period>2011 FY</Period>
    <IsDeleted/>
  </PeriodData>
  <PeriodData>
    <PeriodType>ANNUALONLY</PeriodType>
    <Period>2011 FY</Period>
    <IsDeleted>Y</IsDeleted>
  </PeriodData>  
</Root>
```

My code in SP by which I am iterating in loop and extracting data from XML by xquery:

```
DECLARE @PeriodType VARCHAR(20), @Period VARCHAR(30), @IsDeleted CHAR(1)
DECLARE @MasterID INT
DECLARE @i INT, @cnt INT = @Periods.value('count(/Root/PeriodData)', 'INT');

SET @i = 1;
WHILE @i <= @cnt BEGIN

      SELECT @PeriodType = col.value('(PeriodType/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)')
         , @Period = col.value('(Period/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)')
         , @IsDeleted = col.value('(IsDeleted/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)')
      FROM @Periods.nodes('/Root/PeriodData[position() = sql:variable("@i")]') AS tab(col);

      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblCalenderDetail WHERE PeriodType=@PeriodType AND Period=@Period AND IsDeleted='Y')
      BEGIN
          INSERT INTO tblCalenderDetail (MasterID,PeriodType,Period,IsDeleted)
            VALUES(@MasterID,@PeriodType,@Period,'N')
      END
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        UPDATE tblCalenderDetail SET IsDeleted='N' WHERE PeriodType=@PeriodType AND Period=@Period
      END

   SET @i += 1;
END
```

See **IsDeleted** child node does not exist in first record and **IsDeleted** child node does exist in 2nd row but has null value.

So how could I check **IsDeleted child node does exist or not**  when iterating in while loop?

I tried this below code to check whether **IsDeleted node exist in each row but did not work rather throwing error**.

```
@IsDeleted = IIF(col.exist('//IsDeleted') , col.value('(IsDeleted/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') ,'N')
```

In loop if want to check if `IsDeleted` Node exist then its value will be stored in `@IsDeleted` variable. If node does not exist then I will store **'N' in @IsDeleted  variable**. How to achieve this?

Please give me some guide line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. this i used  `ISNULL(col.value('(IsDeleted/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)'), 'N')`

### full working code

```
declare @xml xml=N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root>
  <PeriodData>
    <PeriodType>ANNUALONLY</PeriodType>
    <Period>2010 FY</Period>
  </PeriodData>
  <PeriodData>
    <PeriodType>ANNUALONLY</PeriodType>
    <Period>2011 FY</Period>
    <IsDeleted/>
  </PeriodData>
  <PeriodData>
    <PeriodType>ANNUALONLY</PeriodType>
    <Period>2011 FY</Period>
    <IsDeleted>Y</IsDeleted>
  </PeriodData>  
</Root>'

DECLARE @PeriodType VARCHAR(20), @Period VARCHAR(30), @IsDeleted CHAR(1)
        DECLARE @MasterID INT
        DECLARE @i INT, @cnt INT = @xml.value('count(/Root/PeriodData)', 'INT');

        SET @i = 1;
        WHILE @i <= @cnt BEGIN


              SELECT @PeriodType = col.value('(PeriodType/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)')
                 , @Period = col.value('(Period/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)')
                 , @IsDeleted = ISNULL(col.value('(IsDeleted/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)'), 'N')
              FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/PeriodData[position() = sql:variable("@i")]') AS tab(col);

              PRINT @PeriodType + ' '+@Period+' '+@IsDeleted

           SET @i += 1;
        END
```